# In.java:16: error: cannot find symbol result=i+j;

Tags: java

```
class A
{
    public void sum()
    {
        int i=5,j=5;
        System.out.println("Sum of "+i+" and "+j);
    }
}
class In extends A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A obj=new A();
        obj.sum();
        int result=0;
        result=i+j;
        System.out.println(" = "+result );
    }
}
```

In.java:16: error: cannot find symbol result=i+j;
Why does the above error occur?

Comment: `i` and `j` are local variables in the method `sum` and hence don´t exist in the `main`.

Comment: Why have a `sum` method if you perform the actual addition in the `main` method?

Comment: Also, please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

The i and j variables are local to sum so only available during its execution.  Even though main calls sum, sum's local variables are gone before control returns to main (even if they were visible outside sum).

Answer (score 0):

Integers i and j are local variables inside the sum() function, so anything outside the function will not have access to it. You could make them members of the class if you would like to modify or have access to them. Beyond this, there is not much one can say since we do not know the purpose of the code

Answer (score 0):

If you make i and j global you will get rid of the error.

```
class A
{
    public static int i = 5;
    public static int j = 5;

    public void sum()
    {
        System.out.println("Sum of " + i + " and " + j);
    }
}
class In extends A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.sum();
        int result = 0;
        result = i + j;
        System.out.println(" = " + result);
    }
}
```